# What are the labels in figure1 in the Paper "The perceptron: A probabilistic model for information storage and organization in the brain"?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron

This figure

[image]

comes from [The perceptron: A probabilistic model for information storage and organization in the brain](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.588.3775&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I guess the first circle (neuron) labels RETINA, the second labels perceptron area, what about the third one? what are the labels pointed out by the arrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circles: RETINA / $A_I$ (POJECTION AREA) / $A_{II}$ (ASSOCIATION AREA)

Labels: (LOCALISED CONNECTIONS) / (RANDOM CONNECTIONS) / (RANDOM CONNECTIONS) again / RESPONSES